# Which appsettings.json file does Dotnet Core use as default, the environment or parent file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

What dictates which .json file the .net core clr / runtime uses? For example if there's a connection string in both. I can't find an answer anywhere.

```
var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's no "default" order. .NET Core will use the files specified in your code. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json` or the Json configuration provider either. As far as .NET Core is concerned they just providers

This code specifies that :

1. The required `appsettings.json` file is loaded first. If it doesn't exist the app fails
2. The optional environment-specific file is loaded next, which may override the first one. If it doesn't exist, nothing is loaded

Even the expression `$"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json"` has no special meaning. It's a string interpolation expression that replaces the `{env.EnvironmentName}` placeholder with the value of the `env.EnvironmentName` property.

The method call error specifies the order, with later files or providers overriding earlier ones.

You could add a command-line or EF Core provider *after* the JSON files to override them with values stored in the database or specified in the command line.

This is explained in the documentation and tutorials, eg [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) or the [Essential .NET - Configuration in .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx) but it's so different from how the Full framework works that it takes a bit of getting used to.

Answer (score 2):

Config is loaded in source-order. In other words, each type of config you specify is loaded in the order you add it in your `Startup.cs` or whatever. Here, since `appsettings.json` is specified before `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json`, it will be loaded first, followed by the environment-specific version, if it exists.

No matter your config sources, everything ends up in the `ConfigurationRoot` dictionary. If multiple config sources specify the same key, then the last one in wins. In other words, config sources added later override those added earlier.